# How to make exported XLS file open on calling machine in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, interop

I have a .NET application that enables exporting Grid Views to Excel, using reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.
This feature is working perfectly when running application from VS, or from the server the application is published on.
But when running the application from a different machine on the same intranet, it exports and opens the XLS file on the hosting server, and nothing happens on the calling machine.

How can I make the exported file to open on the calling machine, not the server?

Thanks

Comment: How can we help you if you don't post any code?

Comment: It's not about an error in code.  It's about a function behavior that works successfully on hosting machine, but not on calling machine on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You can't open a file on the remote machine. That is just not as the internet works. You should just provide the file for download.

Would you like some web site you accidentally visit to open all your programs on your machine? No, that is why it isn't allowed and made possible in browsers.

Note: I guess you are using Office interop on your server, which is [strongly discouraged](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757)!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried adding a "Save As" feature to browse for file download location, but it didn't work either.
I understand your point about opening programs on remote machine, but I'm sure there must be a legal way to enable user to extract and save some data in the form of XLS or PDF to their machine, especially when they are authorized users on the same intranet.